# use semantic versioning for a dependency in Gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, semantic-versioning

How can I use semantic versioning in Gradle, for example in my build file

```
compile group: 'someGroup', name: 'some-library', version:'1.1.?'
```

I like to automatically build the latest version of `some-library` which has all the minor changes of `1.1` version.

Comment: I think it is not possible, and I see a reason in that - the newly released version can have bugs, so you wouldn't want to immediately use it.

Comment: Thanks Alexiy, let's say if a release has a security bug, it is better to automatically use the next stable one rather than picking an exact buggy version. To be pragmatic, how often you go through your projects and upgrade the dependencies manually ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take my words back, it is possible to do this, because Gradle can use Apache Ivy dependency resolution. In your case, you can write

`compile group: 'someGroup', name: 'some-library', version:'1.1.+'`

or

`compile group: 'someGroup', name: 'some-library', version:'latest.release'`

The reference: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/trunk/settings/version-matchers.html

Related - http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/dependency.html